# VBA - Hide rows based on values in multiple Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying my first bit of code and VBA and have been researching for a while but I cannot get it to work. I am trying to hide rows where the value of multiple columns is either 0 (those that have a formula/numeric value) or those are left blank (text). In my Excel the columns O, AB, AN from row 9-1000 contain numeric values and AJ and AK 9-1000 text values. So I want to hide all those where O, AB and AN is zero AND AJ and AK is blank. I could write the basic code just hiding rows based on the first criteria:

```
Sub HideAccounts()

Dim TotExp As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set TotExp = Range("O9:O1000")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Cell In TotExp.Rows
If Cell.Value = 0 Then
Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next Cell

End Sub
```

So now I want to add the other criteria, but I am struggling with the multiple criteria and when I try to insert GoTo statements it does not work either...

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Daniela

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to include multiple criteria:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideAccounts()
    Dim i As Long, hide As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)         '<-- set this to the relevant sheet
        For i = 9 To 1000
            hide = (.Range("O" & i).Value2 = 0)
            hide = hide And (.Range("AB" & i).Value2 = 0)
            hide = hide And (.Range("AN" & i).Value2 = 0)
            hide = hide And (Len(.Range("AJ" & i).Value2) = 0)
            hide = hide And (Len(.Range("AK" & i).Value2) = 0)
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = hide
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Review your answer. It's not what OP wants.